# How to use top n with over() clause of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The following article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) claims:

> One can find out "top N per group" results using over clause.

Please give me an example.

Yours sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an easy task

```
MAX(column) OVER(PARTITION BY column) AS mx
```

You will get the max value for each column value, which is TOP N

Replace MAX with other aggregate function to get another insight, like MIN, AVG etc.

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by col) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= @n;
```